# Knowing if a page is being iframed in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way of knowing if a page is being iframed in?

I was thinking something like `if (window.parent)`, but that obviously isn't right.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (window!=window.top) { /* I'm in a frame! */ }
```

Comment: Amazing how your code has the exact same comment as the question that this is a dupe of.

Comment: @j08691 Stack Overflow is Creative Commons.

Comment: Yes, however it's nice proper etiquette to attribute your solution to another source when it's not your own. Or at least change it so it's not so easily identifiable.

Comment: @j08691 Why change an already good answer?